# Convert jagged char[][] to char[,]?

Tags: c#, arrays

One of my 'for the hell of it' projects I started yesterday was a [Befunge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befunge) interpreter. I have it working for the most part except for an edge case.

I got lazy and decided to read in a befunge program with this:

```
char[][] program = File.ReadAllLines(args[0]).Select(x => x.ToCharArray()).ToArray();
```

I knew I was creating more work for myself later, but I wanted to get to other parts and left it at that. Now it's later and I need to fix the fact that `program` is not rectangular. Let's say I had this befunge program:

```
v   v   <
    @
>       ^
```

The 1st and 3rd lines are 9 characters long, but the 2nd line is only 5. In the way I have my befunge interpreter set up, I will get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` before the program terminates because after interpreting `^` as a change of direction I would try to access `program[1][8]` and `program[1]` is only 5 long. Instead of trying to catch the exception and dance around it, how could I create a `char[,]` using `program` and filling the extra characters with spaces?

I know I could just determine the length of the longest line, the number of lines, create the char[,] with those and copy them over, but I'm hoping for something a little simpler and more elegant. I am completely ok with throwing out the above line if a new approach is better.

Comment: I think you answered your question up there: "just determine the length of the longest line, the number of lines, create the char[,] with those and copy them over"

Comment: Oh, and props for making a Befunge interpreter. That's a cool esolang. I made a shockwave game like that many years ago where you programmed robots like in Carnage Heart.

Comment: Having only one solution doesn't make it the best solution. I can learn more about C# if somebody can point me towards different way to do this.

Comment: You could implement a sparse matrix structure and have it return a space if nothing is at a requested point.

Comment: Can you modify the files so that they are all of the same length (padding with spaces or whatever to get that to happen)?  Could you include a header on the first line with the max width of a line?  Note that you don't need to have a 2D array, it can be jagged, so long as all of the inner arrays are the same size.

Comment: @QtotheC I did have to do something similar to that so that an empty stack would pop a 0...

Comment: The later Funge specs make it Turing-Complete by saying the programs can have any-length line. So including the longest-length line isn't really something to do here.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than re-creating the entire jagged array (assuming it could be rather large) you could just create a wrapper for it.  That wrapper would be able to do the bounds checking and return some default value if it would be out of bounds rather than erroring.

```
public class Matrix<T>
{
  public T[][] UnderlyingCollection {get;set;} //should probably be readonly and set in the constructor

  public T DefaultValue {get;set;}

  public T this[int i, int j]
  {
    get
    {
      if(UnderlyingCollection.Length > i && UnderlyingCollection[i].Length > j)
        return UnderlyingCollection[i][j];
      else
        return DefaultValue;
    }
    set
    { /*TODO implement*/ }

  }
}
```

Comment: Being that this is for an interpreter, speed is a huge requirement (maybe I should have mentioned it). Your implementation has to validate i and j every single time a request is made. +1 tho, it still works.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn Well, it doesn't have to validate `i` and `j` if `i` isn't valid, due to short circuiting, but it will usually validate them yes.  Really though, validating those two is a very fast check.  You'll need to be doing trillions and trillions of fetches to really see a significant time difference from those checks.

Comment: In your solution, if both values are correct it takes a certain amount of time, if not, it takes less time. I would rather a situation where time is saved if the variables are correct and extra time is used if they're incorrect (most likely it'd terminate the program). By doing a little one time setup to create a rectangular array, the proper case isn't slowed down by checks at all, it's just done. I know it's very small times I'm talking about, sometimes completely immeasurable, but I feel it's a better habit to be in.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn The problem there is that the one time conversion to a 2D array isn't small at all; in fact it's rather large.  You need to allocate the new memory, read all of the data for every value of the old structure, and copy it to the new one.  That's not small at all, unless the whole structure is very small (and if it is performance won't likely be a big concern at all).  If you know that you will only very, very rarely run into out of bounds errors you could no do the `if` check and `catch` the OOB exception, but exceptions are expensive.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn Dude, could you provide any feedback on my answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Building on @AndreCalil's previous answer, this might be more performant, especially for large arrays of primitive types. Arrays of primitive types can be treated as a flat buffer of bytes, which can be useful in this sort of work (if you've got experience with assembler or C):

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    string[][] jagged = new string[][] { new string[] { "alpha" ,                                              } ,
                                            new string[] { "bravo" , "charlie" ,                                  } ,
                                            new string[] { "delta" , "echo"    , "foxtrot" ,                      } ,
                                            new string[] { "golf"  , "hotel"   , "india"   , "juliet" ,           } ,
                                            new string[] { "kilo"  , "lima"    , "mike"    , "nancy"  , "oscar" , } ,
                                        } ;
    string[,]  rectangular = RectArrayFromJagged<string>( jagged ) ;

    return;
}

public static T[,] RectArrayFromJagged<T>( T[][] a )
{
    int  rows  = a.Length;
    int  cols  = a.Max( x => x.Length );
    T[,] value = new T[ rows , cols ] ;

    value.Initialize() ;

    if ( typeof(T).IsPrimitive )
    {
        int elementSizeInOctets = Buffer.ByteLength(value) / value.Length ;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < rows ; ++i )
        {
            int rowOffsetInOctets = i * cols    * elementSizeInOctets ;
            int rowLengthInOctets = a[i].Length * elementSizeInOctets ;
            Buffer.BlockCopy( a[i] , 0 , value , rowOffsetInOctets , rowLengthInOctets ) ;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < rows ; ++i )
        {
            int rowLength = a[i].Length ;
            for ( int j = 0 ; j < rowLength ; ++j )
            {
                value[i,j] = a[i][j] ;
            }
        }
    }
    return value ;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the insight. Would be nice a vote from you, at least for the idea =)

Comment: Nope. Thanks dude. I'm going to run a micro benchmarking with our solutions

Answer (score 0):

Man, I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but check this out:

```
public static class CharArrayExtension
{
    public static char[,] FormatMatrix(this char[][] matrix)
    {
        int TotalColumns = matrix.Length;
        int TotalLines = 0;

        //Get the longest line of the current matrix
        for (int column = 0; column < TotalColumns; column++)
        {
            int line = matrix[column].Length;

            if (line > TotalLines)
                TotalLines = line;
        }

        //Instantiate the resulting matrix
        char[,] Return = new char[TotalColumns, TotalLines];

        Return.Initialize();

        //Retrieve values from the current matrix
        for (int CurrentColumn = 0; CurrentColumn < TotalColumns; CurrentColumn++)
        {
            int MaxLines = matrix[CurrentColumn].Length;

            for (int CurrentLine = 0; CurrentLine < MaxLines; CurrentLine++)
            {
                Return[CurrentColumn, CurrentLine] = matrix[CurrentColumn][CurrentLine];
            }
        }

        return Return;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
        char[] Length5 = new char[]{ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
        char[] Length10 = new char[10];

        char[][] Matrix = new char[2][];
        Matrix[0] = Length5;
        Matrix[1] = Length10;

        char[,] FormattedMatrix = Matrix.FormatMatrix();
```

Any feedback will be appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**

Nicholas pointed out the performance issue. I was curious about it, so I made the following micro-weak-benchmarking:

```
        char[] Length5 = new char[]{ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
        char[] Length10 = new char[10];

        char[][] Matrix = new char[2][];
        Matrix[0] = Length5;
        Matrix[1] = Length10;

        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

        stopWatch.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            char[,] FormattedMatrix = Matrix.FormatMatrix();
        }

        stopWatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Andre Calil: {0} ms", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));

        stopWatch.Reset();

        stopWatch.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            char[,] FormattedMatrix = RectArrayFromJagged<char>(Matrix);
        }

        stopWatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Nicholas Carey: {0} ms", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));

        Console.ReadLine();
```

I've run it multiple times, and the average results was:

```
Andre Calil: 3 ms
Nicholas Carey: 5 ms
```

**I know** that this is not a proper benchmarking, but looke like my solution isn't so bad in terms of performance after all.

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I said I didn't want to do in the last part of my question.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn You don't said you *didn't want it* you said that *you'd prefer* something more elegant and simple. Meanings are completely different and I think that your downvote is inappropriate. You came with a problem, I proposed a solution for it.